# Evaluating $\int_1^\infty \dfrac {1}{1+x^4}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate

> $$\int_1^\infty \dfrac {1}{1+x^4}\mathrm dx$$

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There is a standard procedure for evaluating integrals of rational functions. What problems are you having?

Comment: The antiderivatives for this are $$x\mapsto \dfrac 1 4\left(4\sqrt 2\arctan (\sqrt 2x + 1)+\dfrac 1{\sqrt 2} \log\left(\dfrac{x^2-\sqrt 2 x +1}{x^2+\sqrt 2 x +1}\right)\right)+C$$ so I doubt that's the way to go about this.

Comment: I think something has to be substituted, but because of my lack of experience, I can't it....Could you please help me??

Comment: The Maple command $$with(Student[Calculus1]): IntTutor(1/(x^4+1), x) $$ finds the antiderivative step by step with explanations.

Comment: You should answer more clearly just what your problem is. Do you mean you cannot find the antiderivative because you cannot find a good substitution, or you have the antiderivative and you cannot find the limit as the upper bound goes to infinity, or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hints:

$$ x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt2\,x+1)(x^2-\sqrt2\,x+1)$$

Since $\,x>0\;$ , we thus have

$$\int\frac{dx}{x^4+1}=\frac1{2\sqrt2}\left(\text{arctanh}\frac{\sqrt 2\,x}{x^2+1}-\arctan(1-\sqrt2\,x)+\arctan(1+\sqrt2\,x)\right)+C$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't think about factoring $x^4+1$!

Comment: No $\log$s?${{}}$

Comment: Well, yes @GitGud: they're included in the hyperbolic arctangent, of course...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio I missed that, thought it was $\arctan$. Thanks.

Comment: @JH, did you find the actual answer to this improper integral?

Answer (score 1):

$$2\int\frac1{1+x^4}dx=\int\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx-\int\frac{x^2-1}{1+x^4}dx$$

$$=\int\frac{1+\frac1{x^2}}{x^2+\frac1{x^2}}dx-\int\frac{1-\frac1{x^2}}{x^2+\frac1{x^2}}dx=\int\frac{1+\frac1{x^2}}{\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+2}dx-\int\frac{1-\frac1{x^2}}{\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2-2}dx$$

Put $x-\frac1x=u$ in
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1+\frac1{x^2}}{\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+2}dx$$
so the limit ranges from $0,\infty$

Put $x+\frac1x=v$ in
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1-\frac1{x^2}}{\left(x+\frac1x\right)^2-2}dx$$
so the limit ranges from $2,\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#0000ff}{\large\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd x \over 1 + x^{4}}}
=
\int^{1}_{0}{x^{2} \over 1 + x^{4}}\,\dd x
=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{n}\int_{0}^{1}x^{4n + 2}\,\dd x
=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-1}^{n} \over 4n + 3}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over 8n + 3} - {1 \over 8n + 7}}
=
{1 \over 16}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{n + 3/8}\pars{n + 7/8}}
=
{1 \over 16}\,{\Psi\pars{7/8} - \Psi\pars{3/8} \over 7/8 - 3/8}
\\[3mm]&=
\color{#0000ff}{\large{1 \over 8}%
\bracks{\Psi\pars{7 \over 8} - \Psi\pars{3 \over 8}} \approx 0.2437}
\end{align}
$\Psi\pars{z}$ is the ${\it\mbox{digamma function}}$.

Answer (score 0):

The integral we want is in purple.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^4}=\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}{x}}{1+x^4}+\color\purple{\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^4}}$$

Based on the property:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^n} =\frac{\pi}{n}\csc \frac{\pi}{n}$$

(Verified [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432371/prove-int-0-infty-frac-mathbbdx1xn-frac-pin-sin-frac-pin))

$$\implies \frac{\pi}{4}\csc \frac{\pi}{4}=\color\red{\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}{x}}{1+x^4}}+\color\purple{\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^4}}$$

Using @DonAntonio's answer, use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to evaluate what is in red. That leads to a very easy solution to your integral, without relying on limits.

Comment: More of a hint than anything...