# How to calculate $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^6}$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Whenever I tried to do, it failed. Is there anyone to help?
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x^6}$$

Comment: What methods can you use?  The integral is straightforward in principle but very messy if you use real partial fractions.  It is probably no harder to use complex methods, if you have studied these.

Comment: Here is a relevant [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973801/).

Comment: @user153012 it is only a duplicate if topy's aim is to use real analysis techniques as the title says.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: find the roots of $x^6=−1$ in the complex plane, then by the factor theorem $$x^6+1=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_6)=(x^2+b_1x+c_1)(x^2+b_2x+c_2)(x^2+b_3x+c_3)$$
And apply partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

Since your integral is even, we can write it as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dz}{z^6 + 1}
$$
Let $z = re^{i\theta}$. Then $z^6 = r^6e^{6i\theta} = e^{i(\pi + 2\pi k)}$.
So $r = 1$ and $\theta = \frac{\pi}{6} + \frac{\pi k}{3}$. Also, denote $g(z) = z^6 + 1$ so $g'(z) = 6z^5$ which is only zero iff $z = 0$; therefore, $1/g$ only has simple poles.

1. Determine poles in upper half plane.
2. $\frac{1}{2}\int = \pi i\sum_{z_j\in\text{UHP}}\text{Res}_{z_j}\frac{1}{g'(z)}$

This should all be fairly straight forward.

Comment: Simpler method: integrate $f(z)=1/(z^6+1)$ around the boundary of the circular sector $0<r<R$, $0<\theta<\frac\pi3$.  Then you only have to deal with one pole.  It also generalises easily to $1/(z^n+1)$.

Comment: @David I dont think the above method is too much stress though.

Comment: It's not too bad in this case.  But for a general $n$ it gets a bit messy.

Answer (score 1):

> *How to calculate* $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^6}$ ?

By letting $t=\dfrac1{1+x^6}$ and recognizing the expression of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) in the new

integral, then using [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties). All integrals of the

form $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^k}{a^n+x^n}~dx~$ can be evaluated in this manner.