# Find $\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1} {1 + {x^4}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

How can we find the integral:
$$\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1} {1 + {x^4}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}x$$
I tried to find and got it to be $\cfrac{\pi}{\sqrt2}$. Am I correct? Please help me with an appropriate method. I tried to use sum of residue.

Comment: The residue theorem is fine. What were your problems with that? Another option is to transform it into something you recognise as an integral representation of the beta function.

Comment: I believe the standard approach is to consider a contour integral over the semicircle with radius $R$ and then show that $f(z)$ vanishes along the arc. One then applies the residue theorem by considering the two poles that lie within the contour.

Comment: Or find a good change of variable, without using advanced and frankly unappropriate complex analysis tools

Comment: @mvggz I would rather beat my horse with an imaginary flail than a wooden stick.

Comment: Wait for it, I'm giving you something interesting :)

Comment: @mvggz I see that one could have the opinion that the residue theorem is advanced in some way, but what makes you think complex analysis methods weren't appropriate?

Comment: I'm saying this because you can deal with this in a few ligns, with only very basic knowledge regarding change of variable. I've always been taught to use theorems only when there is no other choice. In a certain way, you should be able to prove everything you use, so the simpler your tools are the stronger your proof is. Do you see what I mean? The residue theorem is almost too powerful for that type of question

Comment: @mvggz Once you have the residue theorem firmly under your belt, there is no reason not to use it when it makes something easy. The same holds for other theorems of course. If you're a complex analyst, evaluating that integral with the residue theorem is very likely the easiest way, or at least one of the two or three easiest ways, for you. If you barely know what a holomorphic function is, then it is of course not appropriate for you. (The "you" is of course generic here, not addressing you in person.) There are of course a myriad (well, at least half a dozen or so) good ways to evaluate it.

Comment: Yes I agree, but it's a general way of doing things. If I can answer a question with tools as simple as possible, and yet elegantly :) , I'll do it. For instance complex analysis is not studied before the end of third year in France (I'm french..), while what I used to anwser is the mere basis of integration. It's the way I was taught, if I answered a question with sophisticated and very powerful theorems when I could have done it using very little material, I was heavily penalized. My teacher used to tell me that you don't smash a ladybug with an atomic bomb, this is of course a metaphor

Answer (score 4):

Since the integrand is an even function, we can rewrite it as
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{1}{1+x^4}\ dx=2\int_{0}^\infty\dfrac{1}{1+x^4}\ dx
\end{equation}
In general, we have (*click the formula below for the proof*)
[\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\dfrac{1}{1+x^n}\ dx=\frac{\pi}{n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)},\qquad\mbox{for}\qquad n>0
\end{equation}](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/432371/133248)
For the residue approach, you might refer to [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37372/133248).

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{#c00000}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{4} + 1}}
=2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1/x^{2}}\,{1 \over x^{2}}\,\dd x\ =\
\underbrace{\overbrace{%
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{x - 1/x}^{2} + 2}\,{1 \over x^{2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{x\ \mapsto\ {1 \over x}}}}}_{\ds{\color{#00f}{{\cal I}_{0}}}}
\\[5mm]&=2\int_{\infty}^{0}{1 \over \pars{1/x - x}^{2} + 2}\,x^{2}\,
\pars{-\,{\dd x \over x^{2}}}
=\underbrace{2\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{x - 1/x}^{2} + 2}\,\dd x}
_{\ds{\color{#00f}{{\cal I}_{1}}}}
\end{align}

> As $\ds{\color{#00f}{{\cal I}_{0}}\ \mbox{and}\ \color{#00f}{{\cal I}_{1}}}$ are equal to the original integral we'll have:

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{4} + 1}}
={\color{#00f}{{\cal I}_{0}} + \color{#00f}{{\cal I}_{1}} \over 2}
=\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over \pars{x - 1/x}^{2} + 2}\,\pars{1 + {1 \over x^{2}}}
\,\dd x
\\[5mm]&=\overbrace{\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ \to\ \infty}{1 \over \pars{x - 1/x}^{2} + 2}
\,\dd\pars{x - {1 \over x}}}
^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{t \equiv x - {1 \over x}}}}
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 2}
=\root{2}\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd t \over t^{2} + 1}}
^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\pi \over 2}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large{\root{2} \over 2}\,\pi}
\end{align}

Comment: Always, the master Felix!  Clearly done.

Comment: @Integrals Thanks. I'm glad it was useful for you.

Comment: This is what have been done by mvggz months ago

Comment: @FDP Indeed, it's quite old. It was derived by [Cauchy in 1823](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.2445v1.pdf) . Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Consider contour, which is semicircle (origin at $0$ and radius $R$), more precisely:

$$\gamma=\{Re^{it}:t \in [0,\pi] \} \cup [-R,R]$$

According residue theorem:

$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz=2\pi i (\text{Res}_{b}\frac{1}{x^4+1}+\text{Res}_{a}\frac{1}{x^4+1})$$

Where $a=e^{\pi i/4}$ and $b=e^{2\pi i /4}$

But on the other hand:

$$\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz=\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz+\int_{\gamma'(R)}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz$$

where $\gamma'(R)=\{Re^{it}:t \in [0,\pi] \}$.

Lets try to calculate $\int_{\gamma'(R)}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz$, for example using simple parametrisation:

$$\int_{\gamma'(R)}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz=i\int_{0}^{\pi}Re^{it}\frac{1}{1+R^4e^{4it}}dt$$

It's clear that:

$$\left|Re^{it}\frac{1}{1+R^4e^{4it}}\right| \to 0$$

when $R \to \infty$ for $t \in [0,\pi]$, so when $R \to \infty$:

$$0=\lim_{R \to \infty}\int_{\gamma'(R)}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz=\lim_{R \to \infty}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz-\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz= \\ = \oint_{\gamma}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^4+1}dz$$

Answer (score 2):

First, use the change of variable $x=\frac{1}{u}  => dx = -\frac{1}{u^2}du $

$I = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1} {1 + {x^4}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}x = 2*\int_{ 0 }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1} {1 + {x^4}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}x = 2*\int_{ 0 }^{ + \infty } {\frac{u^2} {1 + {u^4}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}u $

=> $2*I = 2*\int_{ 0 }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1+x^2} {1 + {x^4}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}x => I= \int_{ 0 }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1+x^2} {1 + {x^4}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}x $

Now: Let: $t= x-\frac{1}{x}$ => $dt= \frac{1+x^2}{x^2}dx $ x->0, t->$-\infty$ ; x->$+\infty$ , t->$+\infty$

=> $ I = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1+x^2} {1 + {x^4}}*\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}} \;{\mathrm{d}}t = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1} {x^{-2} + {x^2}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}t$

$ x^2 + x^{-2} = (x-\frac{1}{x})^2 +2 = t^2 +2 $

=> $ I = \int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1} {2 + {t^2}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}t $

Let : t = $\sqrt{2}*v$

$I = \frac{1}{2}*\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1} {1 + {(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})^2}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}*\int_{ - \infty }^{ + \infty } {\frac{1} {1 + {v^2}}} \;{\mathrm{d}}v = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: This proof can be adapted straightforwardly to any function of the form $\frac{1}{x^4 + a x^2 + b}$ or $\frac{x^2}{x^4 + a x^2 + b}$.

Answer (score 1):

use that $1+x^4=- \left( x\sqrt {2}-{x}^{2}-1 \right)  \left( x\sqrt {2}+{x}^{2}+1
 \right) 
$ and make a partial fraction decomposition

Answer (score 1):

If I did this problem, I would first prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx$ converges, then we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-R}^{R}\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx=\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\left[\int_{C(R)^+}\frac{1}{1+z^4}dz-\int_{L(R)^+}\frac{1}{1+z^4}dz\right]$$

Where $L(R)$ is the upper part of the circle with radius $R$ and $C(R)$ is the closed contour made by $L(R)$ and the segment $[-R,R]$. Then I would evaluate
$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{C(R)^+}\frac{1}{1+z^4}dz$ by residual. The part $\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\int_{L(R)^+}\frac{1}{1+z^4}dz$ may be prove to be $0$ if we notice that $\left|\frac{1}{1+z^4}\right|\le\frac{2}{R^4}$ when $R$ approaches $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

One may be interested in the following solution:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx&=&2\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx\\
&=&-2\Im\int_{0}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+i}dx\\
&=&-2\Im\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{i}}\bigg|_0^\infty\\
&=&-2\Im\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}\frac{\pi}{2}\\
&=&-\pi\Im\frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}}\\
&=&\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: How do you get from $x^4+1$ to $x^2+i$?

Comment: @LaplacianFourier, note $x^4+1=(x^2+i)(x^2-i)$.