# Proof that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^6}=\frac{\pi+\sqrt3\log(2+\sqrt3)}{6}$ without residues.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do you prove that

> $$\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{dx}{1+x^6}=\frac{\pi+\sqrt3\log(2+\sqrt3)}{6}$$

My steps:
First sub $\displaystyle u=x^3, \sqrt[3]u=x, dx=\dfrac{u^{-2/3}}{3} du\implies\dfrac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{1}\dfrac{u^{-2/3}}{1+u^2}$

Then sub $\displaystyle u=\tan\theta, du=\sec^2\theta d\theta\implies \dfrac{1}{3}\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\sec^{-4/3}\theta d\theta$

After which I am stuck...

Comment: Partial Fractions should work well enough here.  $1+x^6 = 1+(x^2)^3 = (1+x^2)(1-x^2+x^4)$, etc...

Comment: Ends up with a simple atan substitution and $\int\dfrac{2-x^2}{3(x^4-x^2+1)}$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$\begin{align} 
\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^6} \,\mathrm dx
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[ \int_0^1 \frac{(1-x^2+x^4)+x^2+(1-x^4)}{(1+x^2)(1-x^2+x^4)} \,\mathrm  dx \right]\tag{1}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2}  \,\mathrm dx+ \int_0^1 \frac{x^2}{1+x^6}  \,\mathrm dx + \color{grey}{\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} \,\mathrm  dx}\right] \tag{2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac\pi4+ \frac\pi{12} +\frac{\log(2+\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}} \right] \tag{3}\\
&=\frac12\left[\frac{\pi+\sqrt3\log(2+\sqrt{3})}{3} \right] \tag{4}\\
\end{align}$$

> $$\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^6} \,\mathrm dx
> =\frac{\pi+\sqrt3\log(2+\sqrt{3})}{6}$$

---

$\text{Explanation : }(3)$
Substituting $\displaystyle t=x+\frac1x\iff \,\mathrm dt=\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx$ in last integral

$$\begin{align}
\color{grey}{J}
&=\color{grey}{\int_0^1 \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^2+x^4} \,\mathrm  dx}
=\int_0^1 \frac{\frac{1}{x^2}-1}{x^2-1+\frac{1}{x^2}}\,\mathrm  dx
=\int_2^\infty \frac{1}{t^2-3}\,\mathrm  dt\\
&=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}\log\left(\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)
=\color{grey}{\frac{\log(2+\sqrt{3})}{\sqrt{3}}}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice & elementary. (+1)

Comment: Nice trick?  What reasoning did you use to choose such a method?  Or is this a common trick that I'm naive to?

Comment: It's well known here see:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/985837/find-int-infty-infty-frac1-1-x4-mathrmdx

Comment: @FDP Actually I've deleted my comment answering matha..'s question!

Comment: Nice ! Someone have added a link to the question about the computation of $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{1+x^4}dx$