# How to prove that $\csc^2x=\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n\pi)^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was reading the book *The Princeton Companion to Mathematics*

On page $293$, there is a statement

$$\csc^2x=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n\pi)^2}\tag{1}$$

Here is one method from the book:

> Observe first that
>   $$h(x)= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n\pi)^2}$$
>   is well-defined for each real $x$ that is not a multiple of $\pi$. Note also that $h(x+\pi)=h(x)$ and $h(\frac{1}{2}\pi-x) = h(\frac{1}{2}\pi+x)$. Set $f(x) = h(x) - \csc^2(\pi x)$. By showing that there are constans $K_1$ and $K_2$ such that 
>   $$0<\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n\pi)^2}<K_1$$
>   and 
>   $$0<\csc^2x-\frac{1}{x^2}<K_2$$
>   for all $0<x\leq\frac{1}{2}\pi$, we deduce that there is a constant $K$ such that $|f(x)|<K$ for all $0<x<\pi$. Simple calculations show that 
>   $$f(x)=\frac{1}{4}\left(f\left(\frac{1}{2}x\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+\pi)\right)\right). \tag{2}$$
>   A single application of $(2)$ shows that $|f(x)|<\frac{1}{2}K$ for all $0<x<\pi$, and repeated applications show that $f(x) = 0$. Thus
>   $$\csc^2x=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x-n\pi)^2}$$
>   for all real noninteger $x$.

Are here other methods to prove (1)?

Comment: This is a classical example of [Mittag-Leffler theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler%27s_theorem). So you can find a proof in most complex analysis textbooks.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449909/showing-that-sum-n-infty-infty-frac-1nn-alpha2-pi2-csc-pi?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**METHODOLOGY $1$:  FOURIER SERIES**

We begin by writing the Fourier series,

$$\cos(xy)=a_0/2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\cos(nx) \tag1$$

for $x\in [-\pi/\pi]$.  The Fourier coefficients are given by

$$\begin{align}
a_n&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(xy)\cos(nx)\,dx\\\\
&=\frac1\pi (-1)^n \sin(\pi y)\left(\frac{1}{y +n}+\frac{1}{y -n}\right)\tag2
\end{align}$$

Substituting $2$ into $1$, dividing by $\sin(\pi y)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\pi \cos(xy)/\sin(\pi y)&=\frac1y +\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{y -n}+\frac{1}{y +n}\right)\cos(nx)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\cos(nx)}{y-n}\tag3
\end{align}$$

Now differentiate with respect to $y$, set $x=\pi$, then put $y=x/\pi$, and divide by $\pi^2$.  Can you finish?

---

**METHODOLOGY $2$:  PRODUCT REPRESENTATOIN OF THE SINE FUNCTION**

As another way forward, we note that

$$\sin(\pi x)=\pi x\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$$

Taking the logarithm, and differentiating reveals

$$\begin{align}
\pi \cot(\pi x)&=\frac1x +\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2x}{x^2-n^2}\\\\
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{x-n}
\end{align}$$

Differentiating again and enforcing the substitution $x\to x/\pi$ and dividing by $\pi^2$ yields

$$\csc^2(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{(x-n\pi)^2}$$

Comment: Yes, I think I can finish from here.

Comment: Pleased to hear!  I've posted a second way forward that relies on the product representation of the sine function.  It's always amazing to me when two disparate approaches produce the same result.

Comment: Sure, I will do that.