# A Summation of a Function Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to get the summation as follow:
$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}{(-1)^n \frac{2x}{x^2-n^2\pi^2}}$.

I serach it in Wolfram Alpha and get the anwser is $-\frac1x+\csc(x)$,but I don't have a step-by-step solution. So I ask you for help.Thanks for all the help I get.

Comment: I think that the derivation which you are looking for is shown in one of the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963263/prove-cscx-sum-k-infty-infty-frac-1kxk-pi/1963574#1963574).

Comment: Thank you very much!