# Evaluation of $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^n} dx$$
$$\phi(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+x^n}$$

So I was just playing around with $\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx $ and it equals to $\frac{\pi}{2}$. So I thought if this integral converges then higher powers of x it must also. And for that matter what is the limit as power becomes infinitely large?

1) I tried graphing $\phi(x)$ and I have a at x=0 the function equals 1 but it also equals 1 for all $x \in [0,1)$

2) And at 1 it equals 1/2 and it equals 0 for, $x \in (1,\infty)$

Based on 1) and 2) I have a hunch that $L=1$.

Any rigorous proofs?
Thanks in advance. And tell me about this question's or this type's formal name because I didn't know what to search on google.

Comment: Comment on the notation: $f$ is not a function of $x$, it's just a number.

Comment: The integral is a popular one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/432371/prove-int-0-infty-frac-mathbbdx1xn-frac-pin-sin-frac-pin/.

Comment: Hint:  the function tends to $1$ in $[0,1)$ and to $0$ in $(1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I thought it would be instructive to present a way forward that relies only on elementary calculus tools.  To that end, we now proceed.

---

Enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$, we see that for $n>1$

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx&=\frac1n \int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/n}}{x(1+x)}\,dx\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Writing the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ as the sum

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/n}}{x(1+x)}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/n}}{x(1+x)}\,dx+\int_1^\infty \frac{x^{1/n}}{x(1+x)}\,dx\tag2
\end{align}$$

and enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto 1/x$ in the second integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx&=\frac1n \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/n}+x^{1-1/n}}{x(1+x)}\,dx\tag3
\end{align}$$

Next, using partial fraction expansion, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx&=\color{blue}{\frac1n\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/n}+x^{1-1/n}}{x}\,dx}-\frac1n\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/n}+x^{1-1/n}}{1+x}\,dx\\\\
&=\color{blue}{1+\frac1{n-1}}-\frac1n\int_0^1 \frac{x^{1/n}+x^{1-1/n}}{1+x}\,dx\tag4
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as the integral on the right-hand side of $(4)$ is trivially seen to be bounded in absolute value by $2$, we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx=1+O\left(\frac1n\right)$$

---

Taking the limit as $n\to \infty$, yields the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx=1}$$

---

> **TOOLS USED:**  Elementary Integral Theorems, Substitution, Partial Fraction Expansion

Answer (score 5):

You can also show with a beautiful contour integral that for $n \geq 2$

> $$
> \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^n}=\frac{\pi}{n\sin\left(\displaystyle \frac{\pi}{n}\right)}
> $$

using that
$$
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right) \underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{\pi}{n}
$$
You find that

> $$
> \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\text{d}x}{1+x^n} \underset{n \rightarrow +\infty}{\rightarrow}1
> $$

Comment: I'm 16 and only learning calculus on internet so idk contour integration much and how to manipulate the integral into a contour integral so can you suggest a website or a YouTube channel to learn contour integration. Thanks

Comment: You're 16 and already playing with improper integral wow ^^ However, before getting your nose into contour integration you should start with deep base in complex analysis. However, it may exists proofs of this equality without using contour integration.

Comment: The only complex analysis im familiar with is Euler's $e^{xi}$ representation, roots of unity, sine of complex number, natural log of negative numbers. I'm familiar with contour integration from electromagnetism as a sum of the integrals of the perimeter of the circuit. Again, can ya suggest yt channel or a good website or a book on real and complex analysis that I can buy after my exams?

Comment: The community that reads this will help you, because all my documents are in French !

Answer (score 4):

Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem with dominating function $f(x)=1$ on $[0,1]$ and $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ on $(1,+\infty)$ will give to you 
$$ f(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}\lim_n \frac{1}{1+x^n} d x= \int_0^{+\infty}\phi(x) d x=1.$$

For the computation of $\phi$, you have to show that $x^n\rightarrow 0$ if $0\leq x <1$, $1$ if $x=1$, $+\infty $ if $x>1$, which is straightforward from the definitions...

Comment: But $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac1{1+x^n}=0\;$ for $\;x>1\;$ ... So either you used this in an implicit, not very clear, way, or else the integral must be split in two: on $\;[0,1]\;$ and on $\;[1,\infty]\;$

Comment: @Atmos Because the limit shown in the answer is gotten **after** splitting the value of the integrand as you showed and I mentioned...Anyway, explaining things is better , imo.

Comment: it is quite clear, the point was to justify the inversion of a limit... then everyone can apply the basics formulas regarding an integral... But you are right, it is possible to add a step.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
L & \equiv \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}{1 \over 1 + x^{n}}\,\dd x =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{{1 \over n}
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{1/n - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] &=
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over n}
\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/n - 1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{1 + x}t}
\,\dd t\,\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over n}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-t}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{1/n - 1}\expo{-tx}
\,\dd x}^{\ds{\Gamma\pars{1/n} \over t^{1/n}}}\ \,\dd t}
\\[5mm] & =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{1/n} \over n}
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{-1/n}\expo{-t}\,\dd t} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{\Gamma\pars{1/n} \over n}\,
\Gamma\pars{-\,{1 \over n} + 1}} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over n}\,
{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi/n}}}
\\[5mm] & = \bbx{1}
\end{align}

Comment: Wow gamma, that's beautiful. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Doctorwho2311 Thanks. $\Gamma$ appears everywhere !!!.

Answer (score 1):

> In a comment under the answer posted by @Atmos, there was a supposition that one could use real analysis only to show that $\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx=\frac{\pi/n}{\sin(\pi/n)}$.  We now proceed to validate that hypothesis.

---

We begin by enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto x^{1/n}$ to find

$$\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx=\frac1n\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{1/n-1}}{1+x}\,dx\tag1$$

Next, enforcing the substitution $x\mapsto \frac{x}{1-x}$ in the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$ reveals

$$\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx=\frac1n\int_0^1 x^{1/n-1}(1-x)^{-1/n}\,dx\tag2$$

We recognize that the right-hand side of $(2)$ is the Beta function, $B(x,y)$, evaluated at $(1/n,1-1/n)$.  Using the relationship, $B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ ([SEE THE NOTES IN THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913576#1913576)), in $(2)$, we find that

$$\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx=\frac1n\Gamma(1/n)\Gamma(1-1/n)\tag3$$

Finally, using Euler's reflection principal, $\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$ ([SEE THE NOTES IN THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1/1913576#1913576)), in $(3)$ yields the coveted result

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\int_0^\infty \frac1{1+x^n}\,dx=\frac{\pi/n}{\sin(\pi/n)}}$$

---

**NOTE:**

Another way forward is to use the approach used in the OP of [THIS QUESTION](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1913325/real-analysis-methods-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracxa1x2-dx-a1).

Comment: I can understand bits of Tha gamma function. Not the beta func. But I know the relationship between gamma and beta. And using gamma is always too pretty. So thanks for your answer.:)

Comment: @doctorwho2311 You're welcome.  My pleasure .

Answer (score 1):

Here is a super-elementary proof.

I will show that
$1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n+1}
\lt\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^n}
\lt 1+\dfrac1{n-2}
$.

First, $\int_0^1$.

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^{n^{-1/n}} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^n}
&>\int_0^{n^{-1/n}} \dfrac{dx}{1+1/n}
\qquad x^n < 1/n\\
&=\dfrac{n(n^{-1/n})}{n+1}\\
&=\dfrac{n(e^{-\ln(n)/n})}{n+1}\\
&>\dfrac{n(1-\ln(n)/n)}{n+1}
\qquad\text{since } e^x > 1+x\\
&=\dfrac{n-\ln(n)}{n+1}\\
&=\dfrac{n}{n+1}-\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n+1}\\
&=1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n+1}\\
\text{so}\\
\int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+x^n}
&>1-\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\dfrac{\ln(n)}{n+1}\\
\text{and}\\
\int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{1+x^n}
&< 1\\
\end{array}
$

Since
$1+z \ge 2\sqrt{z}$
if $z > 0$,
$1+x^n \ge 2x^{n/2}
$
so
$\dfrac1{1+x^n}
\le \dfrac1{2x^{n/2}}
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^n}
&\le \int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{2x^{n/2}}\\
&= \frac12\int_1^{\infty} x^{-n/2}dx\\
&= \frac12\dfrac{x^{-n/2+1}}{-n/2+1}|_1^{\infty}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{n-2}\\
&\to 0\\
\end{array}
$